# Smart Groups and ACL

Tags: smartgroups, acl

I have read the comments relating to this matter. Still I just wonder if it is possible to assign ACL ownership to a Smart Group. No option for Access Control on the Group page is available. Is this limitation a set-up "error" or is it a system design  limitation?

Comment: Design limitation. Do you want to explain your scenario to see if others might be able to help you think another route to what you need?